# using blackbox exporter with auth

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Assume that I've API which I need to probe via [blackboxexporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter), is there a way to use
Any auth with the call, lets assume I call to an URL which require **user and password** or some **OAuth** , is it possible? if yes please provide a reference and if not is there any other option to to so as I assume this is some basic requirement .